# Buggy margin with drop cap with some ebook readers

Tags: css, epub

I have the following code to generate drop caps in an ebook:

```
<p class="noindent">
  <span class="lettrine">
    <span class="lettrine-letter">D</span>
  </span>
  <span class="lettrine-line">ésirant</span> développer une relation intime avec Abram, …
</p>
```

and

```
.lettrine {
    float: left;
    line-height: 0.7;
    margin-bottom: -1em;
    margin-left: -0.1em;
    margin-right: 0.2em
    }
.lettrine-letter {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-style: normal
    }
.lettrine-line {
    font-family: "EB Garamond SC", serif;
    font-variant: small-caps
    }
```

In web browsers and in readium, the drop cap looks fine (screenshot from Firefox 14):

[image: in firefox 14]

In some other readers (calibre's `ebook-viewer`, Aldiko), the drop cap is too low (screenshot from Aldiko 2.1.0):

[image: in aldiko]

What could explain this difference? How could I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this too.  File bugs.  There is exactly one correct way to render HTML/CSS, assuming that you aren't using any CSS properties beyond what is defined by CSS 2 (and you don't appear to be).  If an EPUB reader is rendering it differently than a browser, it's a bug in the reader, and it needs to be fixed (unless, of course, it's a basic reader that ignores large swaths of the CSS spec, but those readers usually ignore the drop cap, too).

Because the EPUB format doesn't allow JavaScript (unless you're building EPUB 3 content), I'm pretty sure there's no way to usefully work around these sorts of problems in a way that won't break whenever the reader vendors fix their bugs.  The best thing to do is file bugs and hope that the companies who make the readers are responsive at fixing them.

Incidentally, I filed a bug against Calibre and they said that it's a WebKit problem.  I'm not seeing the problem in current versions of QTWebKit, so hopefully whenever Calibre picks up QT5 (after the final release, currently scheduled to occur by the end of 2012) and more recent builds of WebKit to match, that problem should go away.

Assuming Aldiko is also based on QTWebKit, the same thing probably applies to that reader.